# Русскоязычный файл, чтение, запись.

Tags: файлы, кодировка, java

У меня есть файл, содержащий русскоязычный текст. Как считать этот текст посредством FileReader. При чтении возникает проблема. Считанные символы заменяются непонятными знаками. Проблема, естественно с кодировкой. То же самое происходит при записи текста в файл с помощью класса FileWriter. Как решить эту проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажите, в какой кодировке записаны ваши русские буквы. А также нужно знать кодировку ОС (если винда то 1251. Если винда но запускаете в консоли то 866) И самое главное - лучше FileReader не используйте. У FileReader нету конструктора для указания кодировки. Вместо него -

```
Reader f =  new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:\\file"),"utf-8");
```

Comment: По какой причине не советуете использовать FileReader? И можно по-подробнее как оспользовать InputStreamReader?

Comment: ответил выше

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли!